# Set variable in php and read it in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I know one can set an environment variable in .htaccess and retrieve it in PHP but is the communication possible in the other direction? I would like to add a string which was generated with PHP (comes from DB).
Maybe an answer to the question "what is executed first: .htaccess or PHP?" would also answer my question.

Comment: .htaccess is evaluated first

Comment: `.htaccess` is read first by the web server, then PHP code is executed afterwards.  Maybe if you clarify what you are trying to accomplish we could suggest a different way to approach the problem.